# Change CRS +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +pm=-160 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

Tags: projection, raster

I have downloaded a SpatialLinesDataFrame from http://www.esapubs.org/archive/ecol/E094/150/#data with the following CRS +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +pm=-160 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0.

I need to change this projection to regular longlat and make a diversity map out of this dataset. The problem is that a regular reprojection does not work because the coordinates will go over 180 degrees east. Could anyone give some suggestion how to reproject this dataset and to extract raster layers at 5 arcminutes spatial resolution. This will allow me to stack the raster files and extract biodiversity values.

Any help is appreciated, Niels

Comment: have you access to the paper and an idea of the expected geographical range?

Comment: besides that, [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79447/how-to-change-shapefile-longitude-from-180-180-to-0-360) may provide some insights.

Comment: Hi Paulo, the extent is:
extent(IPcoralrangeboundaries)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -177.4437 
xmax        : 85.15434 
ymin        : -40.68847 
ymax        : 40.12325

Now 160 + 85 goes over 180 degrees east which is correct, because these are the French Polynesian coral reefs. But how to get the Lines over that border? The RDATA set is readily available from the above link - Niels

Comment: My question was about the expected range. I found these values too with `raster::extent`. I'm concerned about their validity. It was correctly assigned? Did you try to represent the data in a GIS?

Comment: Hi Paulo, the dataset was published by the journal Ecology, so the validity should be allright. But ignoring whether that's the case or not I would like to correctly position the lines of the coral ranges on a country polygon which normally comes in regular latlon CRS. One of the two datasets has to be reprojected, preferably the corals because that would allow me to related their occurrence to abiotic parameters i.e. from Bio-ORACLE (http://www.oracle.ugent.be/). Any suggestions? Best - Niels

Comment: I'm not being able to achieve the desired output. I'll keep trying.

Comment: This seems to work

IPcoralrangeboundaries.shift <- elide(IPcoralrangeboundaries, shift=c(200, 0))

Comment: Only partially, since you get a shifted object with no split at 180.

Comment: Correct, I worked around that issue.

Comment: how? Could you share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I closed the lines to polygons and rasterized those to get gridded data. Those were written in a dataframe and I corrected the longitude values in the dataframe. This allowed me to get 'normal' latlong coordinates for the gridded data. That works for now. Niels